# Date.now vs process.hrtime

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm planning to frequently calculate the time difference between set intervals of time.

Performance wise, which of these is better: **Date.now** or **process.hrtime**?

```
C:\Windows\system32>node
> process.hrtime()
[ 70350, 524700467 ]
> Date.now()
1510291942731
```

I need the results in seconds.

Comment: Check out https://blog.tompawlak.org/measure-execution-time-nodejs-javascript

Answer (score 2):

[`process.hrtime`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_time) provides a *high-resolution* timer. Given you only care about seconds, `Date.now()` (which provides milliseconds as an integer) is sufficient and a lot easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it is better to use `Date.now`. To calculate current time in seconds you can use:

```
> Math.round(Date.now() / 1000);
1516869488
```

And you can directly substract from any other previous time.

In any case, if you require more complex calculations about time differences, I would consider using `moment` module.